# firebase auth do not send warning email after changing my email address

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-api-nodejs-client

After changing Firebase auth email with there api like this:

```
              const userObj = await app.auth().currentUser;

              await userObj.updateEmail(userData.email)
                    .then()
                    .catch((e) => {
                        dispatch(setSettingsErrorMessage(e.message))
                        error = true;
                    })
```

I receive a email giving me the option to reverse the change.

The problem is that after changing it in firebase I change it in MySQL database, so if the user reverses the email with the link there is no way to change it in my MySQL databas.

So my question is:

> Is there an option to avoid sending that email?

**OR**

> Is there a firebase function that could be called on those cases in
> order to let me know?

**NOTE: using "firebase": "^7.19.1"**

Comment: Do you execute this code from a server? Is it via the Firebase [JavaScript SDK Reference For Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node)?

Comment: I use "firebase": "^7.19.1"